# Exception catching with wx.pyshell

Tags: python, wxpython

I have an app written in Python and using wxpython for the GUI. Embedded in the app there is a [pyShell](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.py.shell.Shell-class.html).  I have an editor next to it, where python code can be written, and executed in the shell.  Related to this I have two questions due to a lack of documentation and examples:

1) To execute code being written in the editor (i.e. can be multi-lined code with for-loops e.t.c.), should I use `run` or `Execute`?  I am using `Execute` now, since it seems to execute all of the code at "once" instead of "line by line", but I'm not sure about this.

2) If an error occured (including SyntaxErrors), how can I catch this? I tried to put a try/except around my call to `shell.Execute(<editor-code>)`, but the exception is not caught by me (it's being printed into the shell).  It seems like nothing is returned from the `shell.Execute` either.  I would prefer a solution where you don't have to pre-parse the code if possible.  If you cant do this I guess pre-parsing the code is the only option.